# How to insert display:inline into outer div

Tags: html, outer-join

I have 4 analog clock widgets which Im trying to line up horizontally on my web page. 
I was told that I have to "insert a display:inline in the outer div of each clock." in order to get them line up horizontally but I have no idea how to do this (Sorry my html/css knowledge goes as far as changing colors and fonts). If you can help me with this I would be very grateful. The example of the clock code is available here on their website: http://localtimes.info/Europe/United_Kingdom/London/getwidget/119/ (it will be 4 different cities line up)
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an another way for arrangin it horizontaly.

Create a `div`, then put the clock container `divs` inside that paran `div`. Then add `float:left`. for the clock `divs`. it will align horizontally. If you want to

http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/9Vj6Y/

http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/9Vj6Y/1/

Answer (score 0):

Set the style as:

```
<div style="display:inline">
```

For the clocks...